# AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'DELETE'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-permissions

I am trying to add permission for deleting an object.

views.py

```
class DeleteView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAllowedDelete]  
    def delete(self, request, id):
        obj = Mymodel.objects.get(id=id)
        obj.delete()
        return Response({"detail" : "Deleted successfully"}, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

urls.py

```
path('remove/<int:id>', vm.DeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_view'),
```

permissions.py

```
class IsAllowedDelete(permissions.BasePermission):        
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == "DELETE":
             print('id : ',request.DELETE["id"])
             return True
        else: 
            return False
```

But I am getting the below error:-

```
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'DELETE'
```

at below statement:-

```
 request.DELETE["id"]
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request objects probably don't have `.DELETE`, only `.GET` and `.POST`.

If you want the `id` passed from the url. You can access it with `view.kwargs['id']`

Comment: I try it and it works. Thanks a lot for solution.